# Issue with collisioncheck and deleting enemies

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

The issue I'm having is that when my player collision with an enemy with his shield, it should destroy the enemy only. Instead it deletes every enemies in my array. The function called to remove the enemy is used elsewhere and it works correctly.

This is the collision check function:

```
function collisionCheck(){
enemyLoop :for(var i:int = level.enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--){
if(!shield){
        removeEnemy(i, true);
        removePlayer();
        return;
    }
    else{
        removeEnemy(i, false); //This is what is called when I get this issue
        return;
    }
}
```

The remove enemy function:

```
public function removeEnemy(enemyNum:int, playerDown:Boolean){
if(!playerDown){
    killsMade++;
    if(level.levelObjects.contains(level.enemies[enemyNum].healthBar)){
        level.levelObjects.removeChild(level.enemies[enemyNum].healthBar);
    }
    level.enemies[enemyNum].enemyHit(true);
    level.enemies[enemyNum].gotoAndPlay("Explosion");
    explodedEnemyNum = enemyNum;
    playExplosionSound();
    explosionDone();
}
```

This is the function that remove the enemy sprite

```
public function explosionDone(e:TimerEvent){
    stopExplosionSound();
    if(level.enemies[explodedEnemyNum] != null){
    level.levelObjects.removeChild(level.enemies[explodedEnemyNum]);
        level.enemies.splice(explodedEnemyNum, 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: what is `playerDown`, `healthBar` mean?

Comment: playerDown is just a boolean that is not really used in this case. HealthBar is the enemy healthBar that is removed.

Comment: i some puzzled. please check the following that really your problem. you want player who have a shield to collision enemy removed. but now problem is not collision all enemies removed right?

Comment: Could you show the loop or complete function where you do you collision check?I'm wondering where `i` comes from

Comment: Okay I edited the for loop so you can see what is `i`. I've made some test here and it seems it's because the remove function is called over and over when there is a collision. Why it would remove another ship I don't really know since the enemyNumber in the array is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's all still a bit vague for me. You're calling `explosionDone();` in `removeEnemy` but that expects a `TimerEvent`. Is it possible to add the complete class (as download link or something)

Comment: A little vague for me too. For example, `collisionCheck()` seems to return on the 1st iteration no matter what. Assuming that in the full code, it only happens on an actual collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been corrected. The problem was with my collision check and the explosion done functions. Since the enemies were removed only after the explosion animation, it would still go in the loop for the collision. I corrected that by removing the enemies right away in the removeEnemy function.